# Synchronize two JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, popup, coordinates

Hopefully, somebody can help me with it, cuz i can't solve it. It starts with a code that allows other script to run when a mouse is less than 10px high. The problem is that this runs only once. If i hide the popup and after go down to a task bar, or to right to a scroll bar then it doesn't work. I tried exchange 'if' with 'while', but my browser didn't work correctly.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.onmousemove=function(e) {
        var e=e||window.event,
        coordY=e.pageY||e.clientY+document.body.scrollTop;
        if(coordY < 10){
            document.body.onmouseleave=function(){
                document.getElementById("unisoftdevlayout").style.display = "block";
            };
        };
    };  
    document.getElementById("unisoftdevnav").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("unisoftdevlayout").style.display = "none"; 
    };


});
```

Also, i'd been trying something like:

```
var dunno_how = document.body.onmouseleave=function;
if(coordY < 10 && dunno_how !== false){//do something
```

However, evidently, i did an error

As well, I exchanged the two functions and it works in Chrome as i it's wanted, but doesn't in IE and Firefox.

**P.S.:** If second script doesn't check mouse then it will be opening when mouse is going from oposite direction - from browser bar to page. And I need to open it only when mouse movement goes from down to up, no oppositely. If there's only the second script then it's opening when mouse goes to task and scroll bar. Thus i need both of them.

Comment: Why are you doing `document.body.onmouseleave`? If you remove that, it will display it every time the mouse goes above 10px.

Comment: because i don't want it running when somebody go to scroll bar and to task bar.

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't make much sense. This (`var dunno_how = document.body.onmouseleave=function;`) doesn't work because you have a semicolon (`;`) after `function`. Check your console (hit F12) for syntax errors.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm gonna try it

Comment: actually, no. It doesn't work any way. I just need to disallow the popup to be opening when a mouse go down to task bar, or scroll bar in the right.